# How to run timer one after another in android?

Tags: java, android, timer, countdowntimer, android-timer

How to run timer one after another? 
for eg: I am using two edittext and one button, 
after giving input to 2 edittext as 1 and 2(in minutes), the timer should first complete the first given input and then to start the 2nd input.
Then when i click stop timer, it should stop and display the edittext input and the stopped timer value. 
but it's working only for 1st input..but fails in second input.
Here is the code which I tried.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private Button buttonStartTime, buttonStopTime;
    private EditText edtTimerValue;
    private EditText edtTimerValue1;
    private TextView textViewShowTime; // will show the time
    private TextView textViewShowTime1; // will show the time
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer; // built in android class
    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer1; // built in android class
    // CountDownTimer
    private long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds; // total count down time in
    private long totalTimeCountInMilliseconds1;
    // milliseconds
    private long timeBlinkInMilliseconds; // start time of start blinking
    private long timeBlinkInMilliseconds1;
    private boolean blink; // controls the blinking .. on and off
    private boolean blink1;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonStartTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStartTime);
        buttonStopTime = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStopTime);
        textViewShowTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimeCount);
        edtTimerValue = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTimerValue);


        buttonStartTime.setOnClickListener(this);
        buttonStopTime.setOnClickListener(this);

        textViewShowTime1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTimeCount1);
        edtTimerValue1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtTimerValue2);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.getId() == R.id.btnStartTime) {
            textViewShowTime.setTextSize(15);
            setTimer();
            buttonStopTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonStartTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            edtTimerValue.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            edtTimerValue.setText("");
            startTimer();

        } else if (v.getId() == R.id.btnStopTime) {
            countDownTimer.cancel();
            if(countDownTimer1!=null) {
                countDownTimer1.cancel();
            }
            buttonStartTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            buttonStopTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            edtTimerValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }

    private void setTimer() {
        int time = 0;
        if (!edtTimerValue.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            time = Integer.parseInt(edtTimerValue.getText().toString());
        } else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Minutes...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        totalTimeCountInMilliseconds = 60 * time * 1000;

        timeBlinkInMilliseconds = 30 * 1000;
    }

    private void startTimer() {
        countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeCountInMilliseconds, 500) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long leftTimeInMilliseconds) {
                long seconds = leftTimeInMilliseconds / 1000;

                if (leftTimeInMilliseconds < timeBlinkInMilliseconds) {

                    if (blink) {
                        textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    blink = !blink; // toggle the value of blink
                }

                textViewShowTime.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // this function will be called when the timecount is finished
                textViewShowTime.setText("Time up!");
                textViewShowTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonStartTime.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                buttonStopTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                edtTimerValue.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                setTimer1(); //here i am using two call the second input
                startTimer1(); //here i am using to start the second input automatically.
            }

        }.start();

    }
//this is not working..
    private void setTimer1() {
        Log.e("text","tesxt");
        int time = 0;
        if (!edtTimerValue1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
            time = Integer.parseInt(edtTimerValue1.getText().toString());
        } else
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enter Minutes...",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        totalTimeCountInMilliseconds1 = 60 * time * 1000;

        timeBlinkInMilliseconds1 = 30 * 1000;
    }
 //this function is also not working to start the second input..
    private void startTimer1() {
        Log.e("time","time");
        countDownTimer1 = new CountDownTimer(timeBlinkInMilliseconds1, 500) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                long seconds = millisUntilFinished / 1000;

                if (millisUntilFinished < timeBlinkInMilliseconds) {
                    if (blink1) {
                        textViewShowTime1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        textViewShowTime1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }

                    blink1 = !blink1; 
                }

                textViewShowTime1.setText(String.format("%02d", seconds / 60)
                        + ":" + String.format("%02d", seconds % 60));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                textViewShowTime1.setText("Time up!");
                textViewShowTime1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                edtTimerValue1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

The layout is this.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtTimerValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="minutes"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Start Timer" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStopTime"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Stop Timer"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimeCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtTimerValue2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="minutes"
            android:inputType="phone" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStartTime2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Start Timer"
            android:visibility="gone"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnStopTime2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Stop Timer"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvTimeCount1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="00:00"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? Isn't the second timer starting or what?

Comment: yes. second timer is not starting..

Comment: there is no crash. @Amir_P

Comment: couldn't understand the UI..could you specify the expectations from the UI perspective?

Comment: thanks.i done.. let me update the answer soon..

Comment: you are creating second `CountDownTimer` using `timeBlinkInMilliseconds1` i think it should be `totalTimeCountInMilliseconds1` ? is it a typo? or this is how it's supposed to work?

Comment: yes..that's what the error which i done..